# devise an O(N) algorithm finding No of 1's from a 2D matrix[N][N] containing 1's and 0's

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm

Assume a 2D `[n][n]` matrix containint only 1's and 0's. All the 1's in any row should come before 0's. The number of 1's in any row `i` should be at least the no, of 1's row `(i+1)`. Find a method and write a c program to count the no of 1's in a 2D matrix. The complexity of the algorithm should be O(n).

The question is from Cormen's Algorithm Book, and below is my implementation for this problem. Kindly point out the mistakes in my algorithm and/or perhaps suggest a better way. Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int **map;
int getMatrix();

main()
{
    int n,i,j,t;
    j=0;
    n=getMatrix();
    i=n-1;  
    int sum[n];
    for(t=0;t<n;t++)
        sum[t]=0;
    int count=0; 
    while ( (i>=0) && (j<n) )
    {
        if ( map[i][j] == 1 )
        {
            j++;
            count=count+1;
        }
        else
        {
            if (i==(n-1))
            {
                sum[i]=count;
                count=0;
                            i--;
            }   
            else            
            {
                sum[i]=sum[i+1]+count;
                count=0;            
                i--;
            }
        }
    }
    for (t=0;t<n;t++)
    { 
        if ((t==(n-1)) && (sum[t]==0))
            sum[t]=0;
        else if ((sum[t]==0) && (sum[t+1]>0))  
            sum[t]=sum[t+1];
    }
    int s=0;
    for (t=0;t<n;t++)
        s=s+sum[t];
    printf("\nThe No of 1's in the given matrix is %d \n" ,s);
}

int getMatrix()
{
    FILE *input=fopen("matrix.txt","r");
    char c;
    int nVer=0,i,j;
    while((c=getc(input))!='\n')
        if(c>='0' && c<='9')
            nVer++;
    map=malloc(nVer*sizeof(int*));
    rewind(input);
    for(i=0;i<nVer;i++)
    {
        map[i]=malloc(nVer*sizeof(int));
        for(j=0;j<nVer;j++)
        {
            do
            {
                c=getc(input);
            }while(!(c>='0' && c<='9'));                  
            map[i][j]=c-'0';
        } 
    }
    fclose(input);
    return nVer;
}
```

Comment: Could you format the code to be easier to read for other people.

Comment: In the line `for (t=0;t<n;t++);`, is the semicolon intentional? As long as it is there, the block occurring after the for loop won't execute more than once.

Comment: Does the code work right now? If it does, it's not really appropriate for SO, but rather for code review. If it doesn't work, could you provide some inputs for which it does work (if any) and some for which it doesn't? Also, what has your initial investigation indicated might be the problem?

Comment: @kevin I noticed that,Its an error

Comment: @corsiKa _ The code complies but when I run it, it gives a blank screen..we can say its taking too much time for execution, so its seems there's some logical array,Also Im looking for other ways to do the same problem as well :)

Comment: @sean _ I will post a code with comments soon

Comment: Write your idea idea not your code, you could show your code in codereview not here

Comment: @Saeed Here is My algorith. first we get the matrix into a 2 d array map from a file matrix.txt. Suppose the array is 
111
110
000
My algorithm first computes the no of 1's in the last row as it has the leaqst no of 1's .then we move up 1 row if we encounter the first 0,, we store the no of 1's in each row in an array sum[n].

Comment: @saeed - continued 
However if observe the while loop carefully for cases like 
111
111
000
the loop will exit as j has reached n-1 and therefore sum[0] will be 0 .for correcting this I take traverse through the array and if we have an element of the array sum such that sum [i]=0 and sum [i+1] is positive then we copy sum[i+1] to sum[i] as they both will be same by the property of the matrix

Comment: Looks like this question from yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12096022/compute-the-no-of-1s-in-a-2-d-matrix-of-1s-and-0s-where-all-1s-precede-0s-a  might not really be "too localized" (the reason for it being closed). Unless Jason and Alisha are taking the same class.

Answer (score 1):

it is easier to find problem when you first describe what you want to do.
Anyway, seems to me that you have a problem on the if, you set

`i == (n-1),` on the initialization phase, and each time you enter this if the statmnet is correct and you don;t reduce i,

```
if (i==(n-1))
                {
                sum[i]=count;
                count=0;

                **i--;**
            }   
            else            
            {
                sum[i]=sum[i+1]+count;
                count=0;            
                i--;
            }
```

Comment: Thanks!,The code works for some input sets but doesn't for some like 
111
100
000
I think there's a mistake in how the no of 1's in each row ie(sum[i]) is collected.kindly check out and let me know your thoughts :)